# Pandas Dataframe / Styler & email Conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Background: I am trying to create an automated email that gets sent out to various (different) people depending on dates in columns. Email would be sent out if date is today + 10 days, and recipient would be different depending on which column the date is found.

I am running into a few different problems and I am looking for any assistance if at all possible:

1. I have styled the dataframe for email template and I am noticing that when I am viewing in Jupyter notebook the border looks fine, however, when it sends via email, all of the cells appear to be separated (see photos). Why is this, and how can I make it look more like a table by having the borders overlap?

Email: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnReL.png
Jupyter Notebook: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Zay.png

2. I am trying to create conditions to send an email to different recipients depending on which column the date = today + 10. ie. if it is first column it will go to 1 person, whereas if it is second column, it will go to another person. How would I identify any cells that meet this criteria and then identify which column it is coming from? I know how to create the actual if statement around the send_email_to field, however I am not sure how to actually identify the criteria.

Comment: For point 3, you could use [Series.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), with a date format of `'%b-%d-%Y'`.

Comment: @NickODell How would I do that for only specific columns while keeping the other columns as-is? Additionally, I do not believe I can use it once I style the dataframe and it changes to a styler object -- that would cause additional problems if I do it prior.

Comment: @NickODell - I added this CCOD[1] = pd.to_datetime(CCOD[1]).dt.strftime('%b-%d-%Y')
But now I get this error when I try to do the conditional formatting:
TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'", 'occurred at index ')

Comment: Also, if I change the condition to both todays date as well as the dataframe dates using dt.strftime(), it resolves the error however the conditional formatting is no longer correct as it is trying to use the string values

Comment: This question is multiple very different questions in one. Best to split up. Regarding the styling of borders, Jupyter Notebook has its own CSS template which overwrites things an makes them look "nicer". Other browsers or mail clients will have their own CSS which may be different to Jupyter. To be sure of the display you should explicitly code your own CSS, e.g. "border-collapse: none;"